# Online prompt Java : external error or my own error?

Tags: java, syntax-error

Now let's have our code make a joke. Read the code and comments below.

We want to move that prompting code into a do while loop. Wrap the code into a do while code block and check in the while condition to see if who is "banana" so that the loop continues.

HINT: Remember to move your who declaration outside of the do block so that it can be accessed.
Algorithm that need to be followed:

```
/*  So the age old knock knock joke goes like this:

    Person A:  Knock Knock.
    Person B:  Who's there?
    Person A:  Banana
    Person B:  Banana who?
    ...as long as Person A has answered Banana the above repeats endlessly
    ...assuming the person answers Orange we'd see
    Person B:  Orange who?
    ...and then the punchline.
    Person A:  Orange you glad I didn't say Banana again?
    (It's a really bad joke that makes it sound like "Aren't you glad I didn't say Banana again?")

    Let's just assume the only two words passed in from the console from Person B are either banana or orange.
*/

MY ATTEMPT:
// Person B asks and Person A's response is stored in the String who:
String who;
boolean response;
boolean orangse;
do{
  who = console.readLine("Who's there?  ");
  response = who.equalsIgnoreCase("banana");
  orangse = who.equalsIgnoreCase("orange");
  console.printf(who);
  while (response){
    console.printf("%s who?\n", response);
  }
  if (orangse) {
    console.print("Orange you glad I didn't say Banana again?");
  }
}
```

// ==== END PROMPTING CODE ====

Comment: .... it was much better formated without that dumb ctrl +k ....

Comment: What's the question/problem? Or is it a joke as well?

Comment: JavaTester.java:135: error: while expected
}
 ^
JavaTester.java:142: error: illegal start of expression
      taskNumber = 1;
                 ^
JavaTester.java:142: error: ')' expected
      taskNumber = 1;
                  ^
3 errors

Comment: Please remove your comment and edit your question instead. Next time, please don't make people willing to help you ask what's your problem. It isn't polite, is it?

Comment: I have prompted the entire question. I am learning from TreeHouse and Its probably part of a code thats already done.
I think its my fault and I was wondering what I am doing wrong?
that compiler error has nothing to do what I am doing wrong

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place where people do your homework for you. The question is obviously something your teacher wanted you to find and correct in the code yourself.

Comment: You haven't *asked a question*. You've stated your homework, and given your attempt - but not asked a question. Do you get an error? Does it just not work the way you expected? What did you expect vs what you observe?

Comment: I don't know I am new. If I knew exactly what I was doing wrong, I'd try to fix it but the compiler lists a completely different error than I expected and there's no way I can edit a premade program but its just not working.
I have shown you the question and the algorithm
and i am asking what am I doing wrong in the algorithm?

Comment: On a side note, So much haters....hateful much?? so many downvotes
so welcoming to a newbie to the community...

Comment: @JackLi Instead of thinking of "haters" you could start taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) or reading the [help page about asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then you will know why you received downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `while` after the `do` block. **They go together**.

The syntax for `do ... while` in Java is:

```
do {
    // some statements
} while (/*condition*/);
```

[More info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: umm, I think I have that in my code i might have closed the brackets alittle weirder than yours so I will try your way and see what happens, thank you!

Comment: Okay it helped quite abit okay, my only error now is:JavaTester.java:129: error: ';' expected
}while (response ){
                  ^
1 error

Comment: TY ANSWER TO MY QUESTIOn I was missing the semicolon and placed the bracket thing further than the while statement itself (near the end)